# SFML 2.1 and Xcode 4.6.3 - "The specified SDK "Current OS X" does not appear to have all of the necessary headers installed."

Tags: c++, xcode, header, installation, sfml

I'm using Xcode 4.6.3 and SFML 2.1. I just installed SFML and created a project using the "SFML App" template, and I get 202 errors and 2 warnings when I try to run it.

The two warnings are:

"warning: The specified SDK “Current OS X” does not appear to have all of the necessary headers installed. Update your project to use a built-in SDK (“Latest OS X” is recommended) or install the system headers (included with the “Command Line Tools” package) from the “Downloads” pane in the Xcode preferences."

and

"-Wuninitialized is not supported without -O"

I get the error "No such file or directory" for the headers "String", "Foundation/Foundation.h", "Ostream", "Locale", "Cstdlib", "Algorithm", "Vector", "Set" and "Map".

When I installed SFML I first tried to run the install.sh script that is included with SFML. I couldn't get it to work because I didn't use sudo when running the script. I then tried to copy the files to where they should be manually. It said that some; or maybe it was all, of the files already existed, and asked if I wanted to replace them. I said yes. When I tried create a new project in Xcode, none of the SFML templates appeared. I then realized that install.sh might work if I use sudo when running the script. I was then able to create a project using the SFML template but got these errors and warnings.

Comment: i'm also new to using Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlighting part of [the official tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-osx.php) you have already read:

> With recent versions of Xcode you also need to install the Command Line Tools from Xcode > Preferences > Downloads > Components.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow these instructions?

[SFML and XCode](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-osx.php)

Comment: Yes, I did use that tutorial.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of XCode (e.g 3 and 4) on your mac?